# How to find mod for this particular question 19^16 mod 20413

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Having trouble trying to understand how to tackle this question. 
$19^{16} \mod{20413}$. When approaching this question I understand the steps involved such as $19^{16} / 20413 = 1.413028039\cdot10^{16}$. However not sure what to subtract this answer to achieve a $0$ before the decimal point in order to multiply by $20413$ to get the answer. From the answer sheet the intended answer is $11546$.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You could find the remainder when $19^4$ is divided by $20413$ and then the remainder when the fourth power of that is divided by $20413$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Just to clarify is this what is meant. 19^4 / 20413 = 6.384215941= 6.384215941^4 = 1661.231942-1661=0.231942 * 20413 = 4734.632046. However the answer should instead be 11546. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I meant $19^4 \div 20413 = 6$ with remainder $19^4-20413\times6=7843$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh nahh understood how to do it for that question struggling to understand how to do it for 19^16 mod 20413. To give some context ill try to show the question and the mark scheme to it in the comment below.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I wish to receive messages encoded with the RSA public key cryptosystem.
My public key is 20413, 33. The language is English and the alphabet
consists of the 26 capital letters A,B,. . . ,Z and the letter b which represents
space between words (27 letters in all); these letters are numbered as usual
from 0 to 26, respectively.
1. Encipher the plaintext TODAY, using
(a) single letter blocks;

Comment: @J.W.Tanner T O D A Y
↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
19 14 3 0 24
All calculations with modulus 20413.
n 19n
1 19
2 361
4 7843
8 8280
16 11546
32 13226
33 6338
n 14n
1 14
2 196
4 18003
8 10808
16 9678
32 8840
33 1282
n 3
n
1 3
2 9
4 81
8 6561
16 16117
32 2264
33 6792
n 0
n
1 0
2 0
4 0
8 0
16 0
32 0
33 0
n 24n
1 24
2 576
4 5168
8 8020
16 19450
32 8784
33 6686
The ciphertext is 6338,1282,6792,0,6686.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Just to give some context the comment above is the answer to proposed question. If it seems complex no problem, thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$19^2=361$$
$$19^4=361^2=130321\equiv 7843 \pmod {20413}$$
$$19^8\equiv 7843^2 \equiv 8280 \pmod {20413}$$
$$19^{16}\equiv 8280^2\equiv 11546 \pmod {20413}$$

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help now fully understand, appreciate it.

Comment: and if you're weird like me, you can figure out the quotient is 9 mod 19

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  what quotient is 9  mod 19 ?

Comment: the quotient of $19^{16}$ and $20413$, this comes from your remainder. $$19^{16}\equiv 0\bmod 19\\20413\equiv 7\bmod 19\\11546\equiv 13 \bmod 19\\0-13\equiv 7\cdot 9 \bmod 19$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  Oh, you mean $19^{\color{red}16}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner     Method works but only for when n=  a multiple. However how would the method work if n = 33 using your current method the answer would equal to 8079 however needs to be 6338. Appreciate the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

From a simple minded standpoint, what they’re asking you to do is calculate $19^{16}$,  which is equal to $288441413567621167681$, divide by $20413$, and give the remainder as your answer. Needless to say, you can’t do this on a calculator. By hand, if you’ve remembered how to do long division, you’ll get $11546$.

But since $20413$ is not prime, but rather equal to $137\cdot149$, this can also be done by making use of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. All in all, I think the most efficient way is just what @JWTanner has given you.